# Excel force acknowledgement of apostrophe in whole column

Tags: excel

I programmatically modified an xlsx file, as the author had put dashes in, and excel interpreted them as formulae. So, I wrote a script to add an apostrophe in front of those cells, forcing them to be interpreted as strings.

Problem is, those cells show up as:

````
```
'-<invisibleCRLF>foo

 ```
````

If I click in them and press enter, the string is processed and then show up as desired:

````
```
-
foo
```
````

How can I do that "click and press enter" for whole columns at once, as there are many cells, so it's not practical to do it by hand (hence why I modified the file programmatically)?

Comment: Probably simpler to change the code that modifies the file so that it just sets the number format of the column to text.

Comment: @Rory: no, that's too late. The cells display "#NAME?", changing their format still means I have to click in the cell and press enter. Plus, the "=" added when the cells were interpreted as formulae remains.

Comment: Why is that too late? Set the column format to text, then reset the range's formula property to itself.

Comment: But it's not a range with a formula, it's columns of string cells that sometimes get misinterpreted as formulae, when the first character is a dash.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the details of how you ***programmatically modified an xlsx file***

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Unzip, modify the xml files, rezip. But that is a question about the Excel interface.

Comment: Suggest you set the column types as text when you modify the XML. This will also avoid other potential problems such as unwanted conversion of ratios to dates, unwanted dropping of leading or trailing zeros, etc

Comment: Actually, and you're editing routine of the XML. You should be able to set individual cell types to text if that makes a difference with your data.

Comment: I did set attribute t="s", doesn't change anything. In fact, if I do that but don't add the apostrophe, the cell reverts to a non-text type as soon as I click in it and press enter.